# New HTML opens in current electron window instead of a new window

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <input type="button" name="new" id="newmon" value="new">

<button onclick="open1()">monitor 1</button>


<script>

        function open1() {
        monitor1 = window.open('https://discord.com/login?redirect_to=%2Fchannels%2F%40me','github','width=200, height=800');
        }
</script>


<button onclick="open2()">monitor 2</button>
<script>
    function open2() {
    monitor2 = window.open('./monitorTwo.html','github','width=400, height=800');
    }
</script>
    <body>
        

    
    </body>
    
</html>
```

problem: when I press the second button to open a second new window, it just opens the second HTML in the old window instead of opening its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same window name `'github'` (the 2nd argument for `window.open()`) for both calls.  That instructs the browser to reuse the same window.  Change the name so both are not using the same name and it will open a new window.  You can read some doc on the topic [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).